# Prevent the optical drive to wake up (with noise) after suspend and at startup

Tags: power-management, suspend, sata

Each time I wake up my computer from suspend mode, the cd/dvd player activate and make some noise (it probably checks if there is no cd inside).  This happens also at startup. I don't have this problem with other computers where the optical drive doesn't make any noise with no cd inside.

Is it possible to prevent this noise (while keeping the cd/dvd player available if I need it during my work session)?

I am using Debian Sid and Xfce.

I notice my optical drive is connected to the Sata port 3 and I have an hard drive on Sata port 4. Shouldn't the optical drive be at the end of my Sata port?

Comment: You could *probably* disable a required device driver by default, and load it as a module on demand should you require it. It may also be as simple as going into your BIOS config and changing boot order, too.

Comment: @JanKyuPeblik Thanks for the comment. I already disable the cd/dvd in the boot menu of the BIOS. I also comment the relevant line in /etc/fstab but I have still the check in noise at startup and wake-up.

Comment: Going into S3 means powering off the drives and resuming from S3 means powering them back on so it's exactly as if you powered your system off and on. That noise is made by your drive as it initializes.

Comment: I'm guessing that's just what your drive does when it's powered up, and that is going to happen when the power supply is switched from standby to active mode, restoring power to the drive. Does it happen when you power on the computer w/o the SATA cable connected to the drive (but with the power cable connected)? If so, I'd be 99% sure it's not possible in software. Though since SATA is hot-swap, you could add a SATA power switch, and only power the drive on when needed. (Presuming its a desktop, no chance on a laptop).

Comment: @derobert If I power on the computer without the SATA cable connected to the optical drive (but with the power cable), I have no noise at all. This is why I was thinking I should plug the drive to SATA4 and not SATA3 (I have a HDD in SATA4 right now) but I didn't try because the cable is too short.

Comment: @derobert My idea is that maybe the computer access to the drive in SATA3 because it need to access to the HDD in SATA4. Is it possible?

Comment: @don_crissti Ok but I never own a computer which make some much noise just to power on the optical drive. It makes noise for 4s and exactly the same noise than when opening/closing the drive.

Comment: @ppr Well, since it only does it when the SATA cable is present, there is some hope; it's not just on power. I'm not sure if it's the firmware or the kernel that does that—I think you can shut down the SATA link with a file or two in /sys, if it's the kernel. BTW: I doubt changing the ports around will matter (something is probably turning on the link on all of them), but you might be able to switch around where they connect on the mobo—normally they're all right next to each other, so cables should be long enough for that.